# Is it possible to send a Twitter DM without OAuth?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm reviewing a lot of scripts for sending messages to Twitter accounts.

I think you just needed your account authentication (to post in the headers) to be able to send a DM to any user. Is it possible you can't do that now ?

I'm just finding examples with oAuth, but I don't need that.

What I want is to send a DM each time someone follows me, but with all oAuth examples and scripts, they use a Twitter APP, so other users "connect their accounts" to my App, but I don't want that … that is for websites and similar to "connect with Facebook" .

I need just to send DM to some users. How can I do that avoiding them to "connect to my app" ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create an API key (an app, if you prefer) and then give access to this app from *your own account*. It will then be possible to [DM people as yourself](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/post-direct_messagesnew) using the authentication token your app receives.

The recipients of the DMs do not need to interact with your app at all.

Comment: How can I give access to my app from my account ?

Comment: @user311188: Go to https://dev.twitter.com/apps/, select the application, scroll to the bottom, there is a section titled "Your access token".

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to DM them on being followed check out ITTT.com 's features.

it will automate this process for you.

and it's free